# Is there something I can do about my roomba and my oriental rug?

Tags: house-cleaning

I've got a few old oriental rugs on a floor of my house that have fringes on two sides.

I've also got a roomba; he's very sweet.

When he tries to vacuum around the rugs, sometimes he gets caught and requires assistance.

Is there something I can do to help alleviate this issue?

Note: "cut the fringes off" will not be accepted.

Comment: Some report that newer robot vacuum cleaner models can handle rug fringe trim up to 3½" long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would tuck the fringes under the rugs, then let the roomba do its thing.

When its done, shake out the fringes again.

Comment: I had to tuck about an inch and a half of the rug under, as well; just tucking the frills under didn't stop my industrious little friend from trying to eat them.

Comment: *Nom, nom...* Zealous little thingy!